# GCP Logging: who created service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I want to find in google cloud logging which user created a specific service account.

What query should I use in Cloud Logging to find this information?

Comment: I would add one detail mentioning the default retention period is 400 days.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query to find who created a service account:

```
resource.type="service_account" AND
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity") AND
protoPayload.methodName="google.iam.admin.v1.CreateServiceAccount"
```

This (similar) query also works:

```
resource.type="service_account"
protoPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
protoPayload.methodName="google.iam.admin.v1.CreateServiceAccount"
protoPayload.response.email="EMAIL ADDRESS OF YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT"
```

You can see here what the logging looks like:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging/examples-service-accounts

Comment: I would add one detail mentioning the default retention period is 400 days.